# How to Convert Struts tags into Spring 4.0?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, struts

I have some custom code using Struts library which we are porting to Spring MVC

I need to replace

```
SkinTagUtils.findInScope("value1",pageContext) and

SkinTagUtils.putToScope("key", key, "page", pageContext)
```

lines  into Spring or JSP..

Answer (score 1):

If you have `pageContext` object then you can use it to find a variable in the scopes.

```
pageContext.findAttribute("value1");
```

or set it to the page scope

```
pageContext.setAttribute("key", key);
```

Note, there's also other convenient methods of [JspContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/jsp/JspContext.html) to retrieve an attribute from the specified scope and set attribute to the specified scope.